# Mapping / Converting data between the Data Layer and the Logic Layer

Tags: c#, automapper

I have been trying to find this answer everywhere and feel that I must not know the correct key words I need, so I am hoping to find the answer here.

So I am building a project that has connects as such:

Database <> Data Layer <> Logic Layer <> UI

When the data gets to the Logic Layer, I am trying to perform a slight conversion. First, I will demonstrate the code, then explain what I'm trying to do.

I have a 'PersonDao' object within the Data Layer with the below setup:

```
public class PersonDao
{
   public int PersonID { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int GenderID { get; set }
}
```

And a 'GenderDao' object with the following:

```
public class GenderDao
{
   public int GenderID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; } //this essentially holds 'male' and 'female'
}
```

In the Logic Layer, I have 'PersonDto' object within the Logic Layer that mirrors the Data Layer:

```
public class PersonDto
{
   public int PersonID { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int GenderID { get; set }
}
```

and of course a 'GenderDto' object that reflects its counterpart within the Data Layer

```
public class GenderDao
{
   public int GenderID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, with this information, what I am trying to do is either create an automapping or some form of conversion that allows me to automatically match the GenderDto.Name to the PersonDto.GenderID. I basically want:

PersonDto.GenderID = GenderDto.Name where the GenderDto.GenderID == PersonDto.GenderID

AND reverse this mapping as well.

The end goal is that within the UI layer, the user can pull a person's profile and will see something like:

- First Name: John
- Last Name: Doe
- Gender: Male

The user could also enter that same information above in a form, which passes that information to the Logic Layer, which will in turn convert the Gender Name back to the GenderID so that it can be stored in the Database.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are you having trouble with ?

Comment: Essentially, there is already a mapping to entity framework within the DAL, and AutoMapper is already installed.
But I want the BLL (Logic Layer) to be able to convert the mapping so that when the UI Layer sees the data, they get the gender (female/male) instead of an int representation.

Comment: In turn, I want to be able to reconvert that so that when the user enters male/female, the database gets an int representation to apply to the tabular data

Answer (score 5):

You can also look at custom projections inside AutoMapper. The trouble is if these projections need to access other EF things, you're in trouble.

Do your DAOs look almost exactly like your DTOs? If so, I'd avoid DTOs altogether, they likely won't add any value. Just use your DAOs directly.

Typically my DTOs are a small subset of my entities in EF, just a few properties, of what the view model is. I don't really reverse map, since my view models represent tasks/commands. I wouldn't try to build a layered architecture - there just isn't much value in it. A lot of types for not much return.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Object Relational Mapping. That's what things like Entity Framework achieve to do. You can either implement something like Entity Framework, or you will have to write the relational mapping logic yourself.

Comment: Entity Framework already exists within the DAL, and as for the relational mapping, that is where I am struggling. I have tried a number of things that I read and all have ended in failure.

Some examples: 
- Attempting to utilize .Where()
- Attempting a LINQ (however, I couldn't find enough information related to what I was trying to do -- which may have been the problem)
- Trying to restructure part of the mapping using .ForMember()

Comment: Thank loveless, I don't know how I overlooked your advice, but I am going to do research on ORM. IF I need further assistance, I shall return

Comment: Researching ORM helped me to find the answer I needed. Thank you again Loveless